# How can we include <br> in setFlash?

Tags: php, yii

following is my code.here after full stop i want to make sentence is in next line. how can i? help me please with any method?

```
Yii::app()->user->setFlash("OrderInfo","Thank you for placing this order. Our executive will be on touch with you soon.");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Yii::app()->user->setFlash("OrderInfo","Thank you for placing this order. '<br/>' Our executive will be on touch with you soon.");`